# Conversion between function pointers with void and non-void pointer parameters

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have a question related to void pointer conversions. Instead of casting between void* and non-void pointers, my question is about casting between function pointer types, one of which has `void*` as parameter type and another has a pointer to some particular data type.

Here's the code which allows to reproduce the warning messages:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*module_outputMessage)(void *param, const char *msg);

void module_function(module_outputMessage outputFunc, void *output_param, int msgid, const char *msg1, const char *msg2)
{
    if (msgid == 0)
        outputFunc(output_param, msg1);
    else
        outputFunc(output_param, msg2);
}



struct main_state
{
    int msgid;
};

void main_outputMessage(struct main_state *state, const char *str)
{
    printf("Message %d: %s\n", state->msgid, str);
    state->msgid++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct main_state state;
    const char *msg1 = "abc", *msg2 = "def";

    state.msgid = 0;

    module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 0, msg1, msg2);
    module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 0, msg1, msg2);
    module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 1, msg1, msg2);
    module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 0, msg1, msg2);
    module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 1, msg1, msg2);

    return 0;
}
```

This is it, the program is made of two parts, `main` and `module`. `module` outputs the text, but it shouldn't deal with all output specifics - instead, `main` is the one to handle the output. Since `main` is dependent on `module` and not vice versa, `module` does not know what's going on in `main`, and to output the messages, it needs an output function to be passed as a parameter. In order for output to know which state object it's dealing with, that object needs to be passed along with the output function. And that's where conversion comes into play: `module` doesn't know and shouldn't care about the implementation of `main`, so instead of using `struct main_state*` as function parameter, it accepts `void*` which it merely passes to output function.

So it all boils down to conversion between these types:

```
void (*)(void*              , const char*)
void (*)(struct main_state *, const char*)
```

The program gives the expected results:

```
Message 0: abc
Message 1: abc
Message 2: def
Message 3: abc
Message 4: def
```

However, GCC complains about incompatible pointer types (I get five messages like this, one for each function call):

```
funcpointvoid.c: In function ‘main’:
funcpointvoid.c:33:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘module_function’ from incompatible pointer type
  module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 0, msg1, msg2);
  ^
funcpointvoid.c:5:6: note: expected ‘module_outputMessage’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(struct main_state *, const char *)’
 void module_function(module_outputMessage outputFunc, void *output_param, int msgid, const char *msg1, const char *msg2)
      ^
```

So even though it works fine for me, with these warnings I'm not sure if this 'architecture' can be relied upon. But as I see it myself, the only difference is pointers to void and non-void, and it's just one way to use generic pointers for whatever purpose they exist. Is this a bug of GCC or have I missed something?

Comment: Maybe the simplest way would be to change `main_outputMessage` prototype to `void (void *, const char*)` and then cast the `void*` param to `struct main_state*`.

Comment: A much shorter code that will reproduce the same warnings/errors, passing a `int (*pfn)(Type const*, Type const*)` to the standard library function `qsort` for sorting a sequence of `Type`. I've yet to meet an engineer that has, on initial use of learning that api, *not* run in to this same condition.

Comment: @Holt that isn't just the simplest way to address this, it is the *correct* way to do so.+1.

Answer (score 4):

```
void (*)(void*              , const char*)
void (*)(struct main_state *, const char*)
```

are two different types and as there are no implicit conversion between function pointer types you need to make the conversion explicit by using a cast:

Change:

```
module_function(&main_outputMessage, &state, 0, msg1, msg2);
```

to

```
module_function((module_outputMessage) main_outputMessage,
    &state, 0, msg1, msg2);
```

but be aware that the function call `outputFunc` technically invoke undefined behavior as `void (*)(void* , const char*)` and `void (*)(struct main_state *, const char*)` are not compatible types.

Comment: I'm not sure this work on architecture where pointers to different types have not the same size? The C standard does not specify anything about but it's not a common case.

Comment: @Holt in any case it is undefined behavior as `void *` and `struct main_state` are not compatible types even if there is an implicit conversion between `struct main_state *` and `void *`.

Comment: Well, I think I get something, but not everything. If, as @Holt suggested, `struct main_state*` is converted to `void*`, passed around using function calls and then converted back to `struct main_state*`, and no conversions between different function pointers are done, then there's no undefined behavior, is there?

Comment: @CrystalMV the undefined behavior comes from the `outputFunc` function call as C says *(c99, 6.3.2.3p8) "If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined."* and the two types are not compatible (even if `void *` and `struct main_state *` are "assignment compatible").

Comment: @CrystalMV: `main()` converts a `struct main_state` to `void *` and passes it to `module_function()`. `module_function()` passes the `void *` on to `main_outputMessage()` (through `outputFunc()`). So far, so good. The problem is that `main_outputMessage()` actually believes that it has been passed a `struct main_state`. There is no conversion back from `void *`.